# How can I find email messages older than 10 years in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

As of today (Dec 28, 2015) I do not see any email in my gmail account older than 2006. How can I check older emails? I checked "All Mail" folder as well as other in my Gmail and none of them show messages older than 2006.

Comment: Are you sure you _had_ emails older than 2006?

Answer (score 5):

You probably do not have any mail older then 2006.  Gmail will display all mail irregardless of its overall age. After checking my own account which was created in November of 2004 (only 7 months after Gmail first came out). I can see all mail going back to the original welcome email.  See the screenshot below as evidence.

[image]

Comment: I do have a gmail account since early 2000. I do see some emails in my sent folder since 2004. But still nothing older than that. Very strange. Total emails I have so far is over 12000+

Comment: Gmail was only created in 2004 so you would not see mail earlier than this.

Comment: As Gmail is able to import email messages, it's possible to have messages in Gmail's inbox older than Gmail itself.